# How to exclude parts of regular expression matches?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Is it possible to exclude parts of regular expression matches? Take this scenario as an example:

```
FREE SOFT FOUNDATION V2 1989 PAGE 2
STALLMANWORKS 2000 1977;PAGE 2
THE GNU PAGE 3 1977
```

I'm trying to match just `FREE SOFT FOUNDATION`, `STALLMANWORKS 2000` and `THE GNU`. That's easy, but now I have to exclude any combination of `[0-9;]+\s?(PAGE)` that comes after the title. I tried a negative lookahead, but had no luck:

```
(?!([0-9]+\s?(PAGE)))([A-Z0-9\s]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what might be desired here, my guess is that maybe this expression

```
([\s\S].*?)\b((?:\s*\d+\s+;?|\s*\d+;)PAGE\s+\d+|\s*PAGE.*[0-9])
```

may be OK to look into. Here, we would see what we would like to exclude then we would simply add:

```
 ([\s\S].*?)
```

to collect our desired chars.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3WzeG/1/)

Comment: Note that it is matching "STALLMANWORKS" instead of "STALLMANWORKS 2000". This is one of my challenges. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to pair the negative lookahead with every character you match. Your example regexp does the negative lookahead check just at the first character.

Something like:

```
((?:(?!\s+V?[0-9]|\s+PAGE)[A-Z0-9\s])+)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to match anything, really. What would `V?` be?

Comment: It was for not matching "V2" on the first line. Sorry for my hasty answer, I will try to improve my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get those matches, you might use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string;

In your example data it seems you don't want digits before page.

Perhaps  you could use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach to assert what is on the right is not PAGE and then match any of the character class `[A-Z0-9\s]`.

Then make sure that the match end with an uppercase A-Z followed by a word boundary `\b` an can optionally match 4 digits after ending on an uppercase A-Z.

```
^(?:(?! PAGE)[A-Z0-9\s])+[A-Z](?: \d{4})?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?! PAGE)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not
  - `[A-Z0-9\s]` Match any of the listed in the character class
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `[A-Z]` Match uppercase A-Z followed by a word boundary
- `(?: \d{4})?` Optionally match a space and 4 digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8KdocT/1/)

Comment: This fails to match `STALLMANWORKS 2000`.

Comment: @vinnylinux I have updated the answer. Did that work out?